# How to cancel LaTeX compiling in Terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, latex

When I compile a LaTeX document in the terminal like so:

```
latex document.tex
```

How do I then abort the process? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147346/how-can-one-stop-latex-compilation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> will do the trick.

However, use `-file-line-error -halt-on-error` on the command line. Or learn how to edit LaTeX from the compiler if you wanted to be hard core.

Comment: Ctrl-D seems to skip over the current error, but continues compiling. Is there a shortcut to abort compiling altogether? FYI I'm using latexmk

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> should work while `latex` is "running".

If an error occurs, and latex presents you its prompt, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, which signifies "end-of-input" can be used to get on.